# Uncheck last checkbox on CheckedChanged in code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I have a gridview with an itemtemplate column with a Checkbox in it.  I only want the user to select 3 of these checkboxes.  On the 4th selection I want to pop up a message telling them only 3 are allowed, and then uncheck the check box they just checked.  I tried different javascripts, but couldn't get it to work.

Now I'm very close to doing it in my vb code behind on the the CheckedChanged event.  I can pop up the message on the 4th selection, but I can't uncheck the box.  I thought `box.Checked = False` would do it, but it doesn't. Do I need to do something with the Sender? Or am I close with what I have?

```
Protected Sub CheckBoxPain_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim box As CheckBox
    Dim numChecked As Integer = 0

    For Each row As GridViewRow In gv_pain.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            box = CType(row.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBoxPain"), CheckBox)
            If box.Checked Then
                numChecked = numChecked + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Response.Write("NUM:" & numChecked.ToString)
    'Response.Write("STATUS:" & box.Checked.ToString)
    'Response.Write("ITEM:" & box.SelectedItem.Text)

    If numChecked.ToString > 3 Then
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Only 3 Pain Selections allowed')</script>")
        box.Checked = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by Adding an UnCheckMe variable and grabbing the `CType(sender, Checkbox)`, see below:

```
Protected Sub CheckBoxPain_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim box As CheckBox
    Dim numChecked As Integer = 0
    Dim GridCategory As String = "Pain"

    For Each row As GridViewRow In gv_pain.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            box = CType(row.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox" & GridCategory), CheckBox)
            If box.Checked Then
                numChecked = numChecked + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Dim MaxChecked As String = "3"
    If numChecked.ToString > MaxChecked Then
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Only " & MaxChecked & " " & GridCategory & " Selections allowed, uncheck one to make a new selection.')</script>")

        Dim UnCheckMe = CType(sender, CheckBox)
        UnCheckMe.Checked = False
    End If

End Sub
```